# Getting Error in Set the folder access?

Tags: directory, vb.net-2010

Getting error “Some or all identity references could not be translated

Getting error in 8th line

```
Dim FolderPath As String = "D:\Account\HA\" 'Specify the folder here
Dim UserAccount As String = mailid.ToString() & "\" & pwd
Dim objDirectoryInfo As DirectoryInfo = Nothing
Dim objDirectorySecurity As DirectorySecurity = Nothing
Dim objRule As FileSystemAccessRule = Nothing

objDirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(FolderPath)
objDirectorySecurity = objDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl
objRule = New FileSystemAccessRule(UserAccount, FileSystemRights.ReadPermissions, AccessControlType.Allow)
objDirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule(objRule)
objDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl(objDirectorySecurity)
```

Comment: Could you further explain what issue you are having? Telling us it is in the 8th line isn't much to go off of. Have you set breakpoints?

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes I have made up for you...

```
 Public Sub AddDirectorySecurity(ByVal FolderPath As String, ByVal Account As String, ByVal Rights As FileSystemRights, ByVal ControlType As AccessControlType)


 ' Create a new DirectoryInfoobject.
    Dim objDirectoryInfo As New DirectoryInfo(FolderPath)

    ' Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the current security settings.
    Dim objDirectorySecurity As DirectorySecurity = objDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl()

     ' Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
    objDirectorySecurity .AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(Account, Rights, ControlType))

    ' Set the new access settings.
    objDirectoryInfo .SetAccessControl(dSecurity)

 End Sub
```

Give this a shot and let me know how it works out for you?

Thanks!